# Why can't I upgrade my Saka Horse Archers & Horsemen?

Tags: civilization-6

I have Saka Horse Archers. I now have the Stirrups tech and have made a Knight. However I do not have the option to upgrade Saka Horse Archers or Horsemen to Knights.

Why not? Am I missing something?

They are light cavalry - but this is not in wikipedia. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next upgrade for horsemen is the cavalry from the industrial era.

Saka horse archers are actually classified as a ranged unit, not a cavalry unit at all. They also skip the upgrade to crossbowman and upgrade directly to field cannons, meaning they'll be pretty useless during the medieval/renaissance era.

You can check which class a unit belongs to and what it upgrades to on its civilopedia page.

Comment: thx - they weren't too bad as they were such veterans at that point they had 2 attacks & the Scythian heal after killing the opponent unique. I now have a lot of field cannons ;)

Answer (score 4):

Knights are not light cavalry they are heavy cavalry. Chariots or War carts can upgrade to Knights but Horsemen cannot.

Comment: thanks - is there a visual guide to all of this that you've seen? I think I may also need 2 sources of horses to do certain upgrades too (or an encampment)?

Comment: There's short descriptions of the units that do say light cavalry or heavy cavalry.  I think this description shows up when hovering over the unit in the build menu.